# Is it possible to delete specific keywords in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

Can you delete keywords in a string?

I tried using:

```
if "keyword" in var:
  print(var - "keyword")
```

But it didn't work, and it let out out this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I'm probably doing this incorrectly, so is there another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`replace()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/replace.html) for this

```
str = "hello world"
print(str.replace("world",""))

#output
>>> hello
```

so with your implementation:

```
if keyword in var: #keyword as variable
    var = var.replace(keyword, "")
```